# Changing background of wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress

I have been trying to change the background image of the wordpress theme but i am unable to change it.

I tried:

```
body {
background : url('images/squad.jpg');
}
```

I placed this code under design-settings in custom css styles. But i do not see any changes

Answer (score 0):

in wordperss stylesheet file, search for `body` and `html` selectors and check if any background applied to them.
in `html` selector add this property:

```
backbround: #fff url(imagePath) no-repaet top left;
```

you can change `#fff` to the color that is more related to your background image. it's not necessary, but it's best practice.
if your background image is a pattern and you want it to be repeated, change `no-repeat` to `repeat` this should work.

Comment: @lakesh there is no ordinary reason for it to not work! and consider Harresh's answer.. you may are addressing the image incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

Is your css file is in separate folder?

try this

```
body {background : url('../images/squad.jpg');}
```